# Symfony get object from route not work

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

Recently I changed a column of database table to another.  After performing a migration doctrine when I do:

```
$this->getRoute()->getObject()
```

I returned an error:

> "SQLSTATE [42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'p.price_discount' in 'field list'"

if I:

```
ProductTable::getInstance()->find(1);
```

everything works fine!

I emptied the cache done 1000 times and build - all as many.

my schema.yml:

```
Product:
  tableName: products
  actAs:
    Timestampable:
      created:
        name: created_at
        type: timestamp
        form: d-m-Y H:i:s
    I18n:
      fields: [title, subtitle, description, datasheet, returns_shippings, inspiration, use_care]
      actAs:
        Sluggable: { fields: [title], uniqueBy: [lang, title] }
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
    ref:
      type: string(45)
      unique: true
      notnull: true
    active:
      type: boolean
      notnull: true
      default: 0
    new:
      type: boolean
      notnull: true
      default: 0
    title:
      type: string(45)
    subtitle:
      type: string(45)
    inspiration: clob
    use_care: clob
    brand:
      type: string(45)
    description:
      type: clob(65535)
    datasheet:
      type: clob(65535)
    returns_shippings:
      type: clob(65535)
    price:
      type: float
      notnull: true
      default: 0
    votes:
      type: integer
      notnull: true
      default: 0
    weight:
      type: float
      notnull:  true
      default:  0
    iva_id:
      type: integer(4)
      notnull: true
  relations:
    Iva:
      class: Iva
      local: iva_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: Products
    Styles:
      foreignAlias: Products
      class: Style
      refClass: StyleProduct
      onDelete: CASCADE
    Categories:
      foreignAlias: Products
      class: Category
      refClass: CategoryProduct
      onDelete: CASCADE
    RelatedProducts:
      foreignAlias: Products
      class: Product
      refClass: RelatedProduct
      local: product_id
      foreign: product_id1
      onDelete: CASCADE
```

What happens?

Comment: Did you rebuild your model ? `./symfony doctrine:build --model`

Comment: I have done and build - all :-(

Comment: Could you show us the part of your schema.yml with the `Product` table.

Comment: I put the schema.yml in the question

Comment: @j0k I think that he should rebuild his database also. Try rebuilding everything with: `./symfony doctrine:build --all`.

Comment: @SamyDindane from my POV, it's cache problem since the field do not exist but still selected from the `->getObject()` thought the routing..

Comment: @SamyDindane I've done that and nothing!

Comment: @j0k how I can fix that? I deleted all the cache folder and still does not work

Comment: @Mauro no idea except to test and test .. Did you try in prod env, in dev env ?

Comment: @j0k I changed the environment for PROD and still gives the same error. I begin to despair ...

Comment: I restarted the apache server and returned to work ... makes no sense ... Is the problem could be the apc cache doctrine?

Comment: You forgot to tell us that you use apc to cache your queries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last comment is right.

[Doctrine query cache](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine/en/latest/en/manual/caching.html?highlight=query%20cache#query-cache) is using apc as a backend to store the mapping DQL request => SQL request, which is hard to compute, and almost never changes : it changes when you change your model.

For instance, the following query gives different results when converted to SQL if you add a column: `SELECT * FROM User u`

This is because the SQL requests lists all fields, so what became

```
SELECT name, email FROM user
```

should become

```
SELECT name FROM user
```

after you delete the email column, but does not because of the query cache.